# ufunc 'remainder' not supported for the input types - why modulo for numpy arrays does not work?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, division

I have a numpy array `BJD`:

```
array(['2457217.463668', '2457217.484100', '2457217.504533', ...,
   '2457296.330660', '2457296.351092', '2457296.371524'], dtype='<U14')
```

I want to divide each element by `period`, a single number, and get the remainder. I create a numpy array again:

```
periodarray=np.array([period]*len(BJD))
```

`periodarray` is this then:

```
array(['0.5742000365944918', '0.5742000365944918', '0.5742000365944918',
   ..., '0.5742000365944918', '0.5742000365944918',
   '0.5742000365944918'], dtype='<U18')
```

Then to get the remainder array, I do:

```
remainders=np.mod(BJD,periodarray)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'remainder' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Is the problem that one array is datatype U14, the other one is U18? If yes, how can I fix it? A solution which does not fix the problem exactly but provides a simpler way of getting the remainder array is also welcomed.

Comment: Those are strings. Why do you have an array of strings? Figure out how that happened and fix whatever caused it.

Comment: @user2357112, got it now, made them float. Thx